# Can anyone give me some idea about TeamCity, why is it used?

Tags: web-services

I have started working on web services and TeamCity word came across,I have googled it but I am still blank on this. can anyone please help?

Comment: What is that you didn't understand from the google results? Please include details of what you came across and what exactly do you need to know apart from what google gave you.

Comment: I just want to know for what is it used? purpose of TeamCity, if you can brief about it.

Comment: It is a continuous integration build / test / deployment tool...  read up https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/